# Where I am getting the expected value calculation wrong?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Question 1 ) Locking. You have just bought an old bicycle for 80 dollars. You can either buy an unbreakable Kryptonite lock for 20 dollars or a cheap chain and lock for 8 dollars. You reckon no one would bother stealing your bike if it is locked with Kryptonite-too much work. But there is a 10 percent chance of the cheap chain being snipped, and your bike being stolen. If the bike is stolen, you won't bother to replace it. If we have listed all the relevant values, and you act so as to maximize expectation, which lock do you buy?

Planning ahead. You decided to buy a new bike after your first bike was stolen. Would it make any difference to your decision in question 1, if you already planned to buy another 80 dollars bike if your first one was stolen? Suppose you really work this out and see that if you bought a second bike you would still, buy a cheap lock for 8 dollars, and not a Kryptonite lock for 20 dollars.

My calculation is for the expected value of buying cheap lock the second time:

Exp(Cheap Lock) = Pr(stolen twice =0.01)(−80−8)+ Pr(not stolen =0.1)(−8) + Pr(not stolen =0.9)(−80) =$−80.8

The answer is -$17.6

Comment: Please do not post unsearchable images of text and equations.  Instead typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: Your three probabilities add up to more than one, which is a bit of a worry. But please take heed of the comment from @David. There is help with formatting math on this website, accessible through the Help menu.

Comment: Hmm, I would say $-8-0.1\times0.9\times80-0.1\times0.1\times160$. But that doesn't give \$17.6, it gives \$16.8.

Answer (score 1):

P(never stolen) = 0.90 cost $\$8$ EV $-7.2$
P(stolen once) = 0.09 cost $8 + 80 + 8 = \$96$ EV $-8.64$
P(stolen twice) = 0.009 cost $8 + 88 + 88 = \$184$ EV $-1.656$

We could stop here and say that there are only so many times a person lets his bike get stolen without changing his assumptions.  Maybe he buys the fancy lock if his bike is stolen twice.  In which case we would say:

P(stolen twice) = 0.009 cost $8 + 88 + 100 = \$196$ EV $-1.764$

Summing these we get $\$17.6$ as the expected loss.

Or we could keep doing the same old.... and we get an infinite sereis.

P(stolen n times) = $0.9\times 0.1^n$ cost $8 + n88$, etc.

$8 + (88)(0.90)\sum_\limits {i=0}^{\infty} i(0.1^i)\\
8 + \frac {88}{9} = 17.78$

Comment: Shouldn't the probability of bike stolen first should be 0.01?

Comment: It has a 10% chance to be stolen at least once and a 1% change to be stolen more than once, giving 0.09 to be stolen exactly once.